# Как установить границы для генерации случайных чисел

Tags: c++

Я новичок в C++ и вообще в программировании. Я пишу игру где игрок загадывает число, а компьютер его пытается угадать. При проверке программы обнаружил, что числа генерируются в таком диапазоне, где это бессмысленно (**например**: загадано число 50, компьютер предлагает 41, ты говоришь 41 меньше загаданного, дальше компьютер предлагает 25 и это бесполезно т.к. 41 и так меньше) и у меня не получается **ограничить** этот диапазон. Я пытался сделать переменные max и min и через while проверял больше или меньше случайное число и если не подходит под условие генерируется заново, но у меня не вышло. И важно то, чтобы это ограничение оставалось на протяжении всего игрового цикла. Так вот помогите с написанием ограничения для случайных чисел. Вот код:

*P.S. Если что 100 - (100 - num) обозначает генерацию от нуля до num, а num + 100 - (100 - num) от этого числа до 100*

```
'''#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main() {

int num, min = 101, max = 0, count = 0;

//srand(time(NULL));

num = rand() % 100;

string range;
bool end = true;
while (end) {

    cout << "number: " << num << endl;

    cout << "number less, greater than or equal to the hidden one?: " << endl;
    cin >> range;

    if (range == "equal") {

        end = false;
        cout << "computer won" << endl;
    }

    if (range == "more") {

        num = rand() % (100 - (100 - num));
        count++;
    }

    if (range == "less") {

        num = num + rand() % (100 - (100 - num));
        count++;
    }
}

cout << "guessed in " << count << " attempts" << endl;

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}'''
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проще всего сгенерировать целое случайное число в диапазоне `[a;b]`, т.е. от `a` до `b` включительно -

```
rand()%(b-a+1)+a
```

Более правильный способ - использование `<random>` -

```
std::random_device r;
std::default_random_engine e(r());
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(a,b);
```

После этого генерация очередного случайного числа с равномерным распределением в диапазоне `[a;b]` -

```
int random_number = dist(e);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
template <int f, int s >
class Urand {
    std::mt19937 en;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> d{ f, s };
public:
    int  operator ()() { return d(en); }
};
```

Можно получать последовательность случайных чисел(возьмем, например диапазон -50 ... 150:

```
constexpr size_t sz = 10;
int array[sz];
std::generate(array, array + sz, Urand<-50, 150>());
```

Можно получать такой массив и во время компиляции, но это уже другая тема...